# How to create a progressive JPEG image on Android

Tags: java, android, jpeg

I need to send images over a *very* low-bandwidth connection from an android phone (down to 10kByte/s) and would like to send them in progressive (interlaced) mode so that the user at the other end starts seeing the image already during the lengthy transfer. Right now, I am creating the image with the regular photo app:

`Intent takePictureIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);`

But this creates *non-progressive* photos and I have not been able to discover how to convince it to do otherwise. The second option I explored (reading and re-compressing the taken image) got foiled because the Bitmap's compress method does not allow any encoding parameters besides format name and compression factor as far as I could determine:

`bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 80, out);`

My preferred solution would be to instruct the photo app to save in progressive mode.

The next best option would be a Java algorithm that losslessly converts the stored jpeg to progressive (jpegtran does this on Linux, but it is in C and relies on libjepeg).

The next best would a method to specify the relevant encoding parameters to android allowing me to re-compress it, or an alternative Java library that does the same.

Further research revealed that the algorithms are already there (`/system/lib/libjpeg.so`) with the sources in `~/android-sdk-linux/source-tree/external/jpeg` -- but there do not seem to be JNI wrappers readily available.

Comment: Just a note: "progressive" is exactly what you get: from top to bottom.  What you're looking for is called "interlaced".  JPEG output format does not support interlacing.  PNG does, so you need to look at creating interlaced PNG image.

Comment: @AleksG Sorry, but I have to disagree. Please check out [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JPEG) section 'JPEG compression'. As I mentioned in the question, this format is easy to create on 'Linux' using jpegtran.

Comment: What is current situation with encoding progressive JPEG in Android?

Answer (score 1):

Have you seen this document?

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/imageio/plugins/jpeg/JPEGImageWriteParam.html

It seems to have write progressive support.

Alternatively, you could use e.g. [OpenJPEG](http://code.google.com/p/openjpeg/wiki/DocJ2KCodec#Description) through JNI. See http://www.linux-mag.com/id/7697/ as a start.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, but I need the solution in Android, and JPEGImageWriteParam is not available there. Using the libjpeg (Openjpeg) directly I just did not get the chance to work on.

Comment: I got it. But the JDK source is available, and maybe you could reuse that/those source classes?

Comment: They are available and I have tried - but if you try to pull that functionality across, you are pulling several dozen classes along with ti. Most of the packages in this area are not supported by Android.